# Why does realloc mess up the value?

Tags: c, memory, allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int* list_of_numbers;
    list_of_numbers = (int*)malloc(1);
    list_of_numbers[0] = 10;
    printf("Value at 0 before realloc: %d", list_of_numbers[0]);
    list_of_numbers = (int*)realloc(list_of_numbers, 2 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Value at 0 after realloc: %d", list_of_numbers[0]);//this one prints -83920310 instead of 10

    system("pause");
}
```

My assignment is asking me to allocate memory for one number and that works fine
Then I need to reallocate it for 2 numbers to fit and as soon as I do that my first value is replaced by random value.
Why? and how to fix :D

Comment: In `list_of_numbers = (int*)malloc(1);` **one byte** is not enough to store `int` value.

Comment: `malloc(1);` allocates 1 byte.  Certainly insufficient for `list_of_numbers[0] = 10;`.  Try `list_of_numbers = malloc(sizeof *list_of_numbers);`

Answer (score 2):

`malloc(1)` is too small to hold an `int`, so writing one there is Undefined Behavior. It's only by coincidence that it seems to work at first. Do `malloc(sizeof(int))` or `malloc(sizeof(*list_of_numbers))` instead.